# Running API using R to get the authentication token from a server

Tags: r, json, auth-token

After running the API I am getting "NULL" authentication code.

JSON data input format is:

```json
data={
    "list":[
            {"response": {"appId":"appID","userId":"userId","userPwd":"password"}},
            {"selectParList":{}},
            {"uploadParList":[{}]}
        ]
}
```

Expected output:

```json
{
   "wsInfoMsg":    {
      "statusCode": "200",
      "statusMessage": "User <userId> Login Successfully .!!!",
      "errorMessage": "",
      "errorCause": "",
      "authToken": "MjAyMDA2MTAwMDAwMDAwMDAy"       
   },
   "wsInfoQry": []
}
```

R code snippet:

```r
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)


url <- "url"


data <- list(
  list(
    response = list(
      appId = "appID",
      userId = "userID",
      userPwd = "userPWD"
    )
  ),
  list(selectParList = list()),
  list(uploadParList = list())
)

response <- POST(url, body=toJSON(data), encode = "json", content_type("application/json"))

token <- content(response)$wsInfoMsg$authToken

print(token)
```

The output is NULL

Note: `url`, `appID`, `userID`, `userPWD` to be replaced by actual values

Comment: Welcome to SO! I'm afraid your issue is currently not reproducible for others. What you may want to do is shift your problem from  "response from unknown API is not what expected"  to something more specific, like "here's json payload and curl example from documentation, I'd like to verify  if my R implementation is compatible", for this you don't need to share your API credentials nor the targeted service. So to help others help you, you should at least add relevant parts from API documentation, CURL example would be ideal.  Also check https://curlconverter.com/r/ for converting curl to httr.